# Huawei u8800 restarts

Tags: applications, huawei-u8800

I am having troubles for weeks and still can't do anything

I can only go into Android recovery, and can wipe data. Then after 2-3 restarts, Huawei X5 boots. If I restart phone, a lot of windows showing stop activities shows. I can't even click restart button.

So, I put 2.3.5 first, then Gingerbread "custom app" to download in external and internal SD. After wiping in Android recovery, I power off. With <kbd>+ -</kbd> and <kbd>power</kbd>, I made it update. This time, updates were successful. Before, it was always failing.

It could make updates. But after updates, it could not start again. After loading Huawei logo, it restarts and can't go to homescreen. So, I had to go to Adnroid recovery again and wipe data.

I can't change recovery because I can't install superuser. Superuser should be restarted, but if it is restarted, phone can't start.

I can only use SD card, after wiping data, until one restart. How can I change without rooting recovery? And I change recovery, does this help? I don't know what the problem is.

In my sd card, there are dload s, aurora 4.0 s, cyangane , partition zip and like that a lot of zips but in android recovery , when i try to install, it fails. Only i can install in update mode (Volume up volume down and power), the one in dload file.After updating that (to 2.3.5.), it restarts 1-2 times maybe, then i can go into desktop and settings. But if i restart again, it breaks. I am bored of this. What is wrong with phone? I downloaded a lot of dload files, maybe i am not using the proper one.

Comment: Why did you start wiping data? What happened before?

Comment: Last year i cracked the screen. So, 2 weeks ago, the screen was changed. THen i installed aurora v20. It was good but discharhing fast and my flash were not working. And i could not see my internal sd. It was not mounted. So, i wanted to go back to stock rom to see what will happen. I wiped in cwm . After a few trying, it went this loop. NOw my phone is open, 2.3.5. But if i restarts, it will again not open, maybe open but a lot of popups that show stop activity. If i dont wipe datya in android recovery, i cant open the phone.

Comment: I am waiting helps..

Comment: Sorry, I can't help you. I'm not familiar with Huawei and what tools to use. Hopefully somebody else can help you.

Comment: I think it is not about Huawei. I hope someone helps. I am trying for 2 weeks :(